# jQuery flotcharts - tooltip only for one series

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flot

How to disable tooltip for a given series?
I have 2 data series. I want tooltip only for one.

My tooltip options:

```
tooltip: true,
        tooltipOpts: {
            id: 'flotTip',
            content: '%x : %y km/h',
            shifts: {
                x: 10,
                y: 20,
            },
            defaultTheme: true,
            lines: {
                track: false,
                threshold: 0.05,
            },
        }
    };

PLOT = $.plot($("#route-plot"), [V, PRK], options);
```

Comment: Can you add an working example in a jsFiddle please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a format string you can also use a function for the `content` option. Replace

```
content: '%x : %y km/h',
```

with something like this

```
content: function(label, xval, yval, flotItem) {
    if (flotItem.seriesIndex == 0) { // you could also use the label
        return xval.toString() + ' : ' + yval.toString() + ' km/h';
    }
    else {
        return false; // this means no tooltip is generated
    }
},
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zzcjapd5/1/) for a working example (only the yellow chart has tooltips).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a simple if statement.

If you already know the specific series label and its static you can use something like below.

```
 if(item.series.label != "Your Series Label you don't want to show")
{
 //Do tooltip show work
}
```

Have a look at this fiddle - [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxtFc/242/)

Comment: This does not work for the tooltip plugin which Sko uses. But it works if you implement the tooltip yourself.